# Artifactory OSS:: System Logs - not reachable within UI "You are not authorized to view this page"

Tags: artifactory

I'm experiencing strange issue.
Artifactory OSS 7.16.3 installed
Internal admin account cannot reach Administration > Monitoring > System Logs. Error says: "You are not authorized to view this page"

If I'll Navigate to Administration > Services > System Logs - all is good.

They can be reached from server. Is that limitation of OSS version?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce it on my end as well on version 7.19.

I have opened an internal bug (JFUI-6623, it's a private project) for this on JFrog Jira.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue after the license expired.

Comment: I can understand that application will behave differently once license got expired but Free Artifactory **OSS** 7.16.3? Anyway instance is wiped, thus didn't bother more about issue. That was only one OSS which I've used, as on paid servers never seen such case.